# Starbound server not working?

Tags: starbound, server-administration

My Starbound server is not working; when I try to log on to the server it says "wrong password" but I have not set a password. My friend can join but I can't. Does anyone have any ideas what to do?

Comment: On what OS you are running the server? Windows, Mac OS, Linux 32 or Linux 64? Your friend conects to the same server?

Comment: Figured out what was going on guys. i found that i had to run the server and fully load it up before starting Starbound. i have this feeling that it was some interruption with running the server and Starbound at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In the `default_configuration.cfg` file there should be this code:

> ```
> "serverPasswords" : [
>   "",
>   "duckies",
>   "swordfish",
> ],
> ```

Which denotes the blank password, and the two default passwords. Either try one of the default passwords, or delete them all and create your own.

Comment: i have deleted both of them so the server has no password but it dose not work for me. but for my brother it dose. its so annoying iam ripping my hair off!!

Comment: Try setting a password, and see what happens then.

Comment: I tryed but it's still telling me Wrong password.

Answer (score 1):

As of 12 Feb, 2015...
Modify the `"serverUsers"` entry in the `starbound.config` file.
More specifically, `<SteamApps>/common/Starbound/giraffe_storage/starbound.config`
I'm guessing here, but I imagine `giraffe_storage` will change with future patches.
Here's an example:

```
"serverUsers" : {
  "fred" : {
    "admin" : true,
    "password" : "hunter2"
  },
  "george" : {
    "admin" : false,
    "password" : "swordfish"
  }
},
```

Check the dev blog post for more info:
http://playstarbound.com/february-17-server-configuration-changes/

Answer (score -3):

what ip are you using. if your NOT using your ipv4, USE it. when you use your ip address your telling your computer to talk to itself. if you use your ipv4 it should be fixed.